# Different languages in a website

Tags: php, html, cakephp, xhtml, utf-8

I have different translations to put on a website which include French, Spanish, German & Russian.

The translations are stored in a file and just echoed through PHP using the CakePHP framework.  Anyway, the problem is here:

When I don't have any meta tag with the charset utf-8, the French, Spanish & German are fine but the Russian is total mess.

When I put the meta tag though, some characters from French, Spanish & German screw up (they show as a question mark) and the Russian is fine.

Any idea how can I have one meta tag good for all?

Answer (score 1):

1. No meta tags affects encoding. An HTTP header does.
2. Like Basile said, Russian UTF-8 displays all right, as long as it's UTF-8, not some other encoding.

so. to solve ANY encoding problem

1. Be sure that your server sends proper `Content-type` header with encoding. Use `header()` to set it manually.
2. Be sure that your translations are actually in utf-8.
3. That's all.

Comment: russian is displaying ok in utf-8 but why French, german and spanish no? :/

Comment: Browsers *do* pay attention to meta tags that describe character encoding if the HTTP headers don't specify anything.

Comment: "but why French, german and spanish no"? those languages do not behave any different from russian - if properly used like shrapnel suggested.

Answer (score 0):

It might be related to a matter of character encoding. Unicode (& UTF-8) have cyrillic letters, but many russian texts used to be in a different encoding, like KOI.